# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object SB.PCIO.X.HC.RHUB.SSO8

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, bios

I tried to install ubuntu 18.04 with a dual boot but when I choose "Install ubuntu" or even "try ubuntu without installing", I'm facing a BIOS Error that I think is related to my RTX 2060 graphic card. I can hear that blink sound when ubuntu starts, but I'm seeing this on my screen. Secure boot is disabled and legacy mode too. Any ideas to solve it? Is there any way to install Nvidia drivers before ubuntu installation? Thanks!
[image: Bios error while booting]

Comment: Installing drivers before there's an OS is impossible (and nonsensical). First of all update UEFI, if available. If none or the problem persists even with the new firmware then boot in safe graphics mode or use `nomodeset`. Make sure to then select the option to install 3rd party drivers, etc. because that is what will install Nvidia graphics drivers among other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added *nomodeset* in the kernel configuration file and the problem got solve.