# Error Boot Message on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have this  Boot Error Massage on my Laptop Acer Aspire A514-54, on Ubuntu 22.04, has anyone tip about it, please?

[image: Error Boot Message]

Comment: See the comments on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367587/acpi-bios-error-bug-failure-creating-named-object-sb-pcio-x-hc-rhub-sso8).

Comment: Assuming that you can at least boot into Recovery Mode, or get to root, in the `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site for your make/model #, or motherboard make/model #, and check for a newer BIOS. You'll probably need Windows to install it.